# DirectShow memory doesn't release properly

Tags: c#, memory, marshalling, directshow, directshow.net

I'm stuck with a memory issue using directshow and, more specifically, the directshow.net library

The goal is reproducing an AVI file and everything works fine, except for the fact the memory doesn't release at all after calling Marshal.ReleaseComObject.

Few steps I'm following on creating the graph

1. Create IFilterGraph2 object
2. Create ICaptureGraphBuilder2
3. Set Filtergraph
4. Adding the source filter using IFilterGraph2.AddSourceFilter
5. Create and configuring ISampleGrabber
6. Adding ISampleGrabber
7. Render the stream

At this point if I remove the filters from the graph and calling Marshal.ReleaseComObject on ISampleGrabber, IFilterGraph2 and ICaptureGraphBuilder2 to free up, the memory still retained and never unloads.

The problem is that if I play many files without shutting down the whole process I eventually receive a 80004001 error from Com Objects, which sounds a bit weird

Thanks in advance for reading and for any further suggestion

---

EDIT: Adding code from directshow.net library sample, which has the same behaviour

```
    private void SetupGraph(Control hWin, string FileName)
    {
        int hr;

        // Get the graphbuilder object
        m_FilterGraph = new FilterGraph() as IFilterGraph2;

        // Get a ICaptureGraphBuilder2 to help build the graph
        ICaptureGraphBuilder2 icgb2 = new CaptureGraphBuilder2() as ICaptureGraphBuilder2;

        try
        {
            // Link the ICaptureGraphBuilder2 to the IFilterGraph2
            hr = icgb2.SetFiltergraph(m_FilterGraph);
            DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR( hr );


            // Add the filters necessary to render the file.  This function will
            // work with a number of different file types.
            IBaseFilter sourceFilter = null;
            hr = m_FilterGraph.AddSourceFilter(FileName, FileName, out sourceFilter);
            DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR( hr );

            // Get the SampleGrabber interface
            m_sampGrabber = (ISampleGrabber) new SampleGrabber();
            IBaseFilter baseGrabFlt = (IBaseFilter) m_sampGrabber;

            // Configure the Sample Grabber
            ConfigureSampleGrabber(m_sampGrabber);

            // Add it to the filter
            hr = m_FilterGraph.AddFilter( baseGrabFlt, "Ds.NET Grabber" );
            DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR( hr );

            // Connect the pieces together, use the default renderer
            hr = icgb2.RenderStream(null, null, sourceFilter, baseGrabFlt, null);
            DsError.ThrowExceptionForHR( hr );

            // Now that the graph is built, read the dimensions of the bitmaps we'll be getting
            SaveSizeInfo(m_sampGrabber);

            // Configure the Video Window
            IVideoWindow videoWindow = m_FilterGraph as IVideoWindow;
            ConfigureVideoWindow(videoWindow, hWin);

            // Grab some other interfaces
            m_mediaEvent = m_FilterGraph as IMediaEvent;
            m_mediaCtrl = m_FilterGraph as IMediaControl;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (icgb2 != null)
            {
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(icgb2);
                icgb2 = null;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: It's hard to do much without the relevant code - there's any number of things that you might have done wrong. Memory doesn't really have to be unloaded anyway. Also, note that `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` is far trickier than you might think - COM objects in .NET are actually managed, so this isn't equivalent to calling `->Release` in native code (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/03/01/marshal-releasecomobject-considered-dangerous.aspx). Cut down your code to the bare minimum that displays your issue (you can usually ignore error handling as well), and post it here.

Comment: At first glance, it seems that you are reusing the managed COM wrappers somewhere (eventually causing the 80004001 or "Not implemented") - `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` is going to completely destroy that. If you're doing manual reference counting, make sure to actually do it right - *never* use a COM wrapper after `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` has been called on it.

Comment: Thanks both, added some code from the online samples and acting with the same behaviour. I start to guess dshow is not the way to go these days..

Comment: Well, you're releasing the `icgb2` in the finally, but the `RenderStream` method is asynchronous - you're simply connecting the capture pins to the rendering. So at some point in the future, when the COM object is actually released, the rendering can no longer work properly. Also, setting `icgb2` to null is a sign of cargo culting - as `icgb2` is a local, it doesn't make any difference whatsoever. Does the original sample code also show the issue? It doesn't seem broken to me (though it is *full* of cargo culting and other errors).

Comment: @Luaan yes it shows the same mem errors. The only thing that really differs from my code is the fact that ICaptureGraphBuilder2 is a module variable, not a local, and it's release after the rendering is complete and after receiving the proper media event

Comment: On top of that, what really wrecks me up is that i quickly wrote some code in unmanaged c++, calling it from a managed c# form, and it works like a charm. I guess you are right on how different is calling a ->Release() compared to calling a Marshal.ReleaseComObject

Comment: Well, if you're feeling adventurous, try using `Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject` - at least that will try to release the COM object immediately. The .NET wrapper will exist until it's collected, and some of the resources in the COM object might as well (that all depends on the implementation of the COM object, the caller has no control over that). At least it should show you what you're leaking - the improperly reused interfaces should give you errors. If your application has low managed memory needs, it might be worthwile to try `GC.Collect` *for testing* - it might help release the RCWs.

Comment: Using a memory profiler (both .NET and unmanaged) might also be worthwile. There might be trouble with pinned handles on the .NET side (preventing proper garbage collection), for example.

Comment: Yep, I use to run a memprofiler almost always and checkin for pinned objects was the first thing I did. I also use a GC.Collect after releasing COM Objects and tried out FinalReleaseComObject as suggested but nothing changes. Unfortunately I'm forced to use DSHow so I'll probably take the approach to write down a cpp wrapper to use it in net. Thanks once again @Luaan